# Django Rest Framework + django_filter: filter for name or none if nothing is provided

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using Django rest Framework together with django_filters.
(I've tried to simplify/reduce the code here as much as possible)

How can I force django_filters to filter for constraints__name=None (or constraints=None) if no constraint is specified in the request?

Let's say I have this model:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    constraints = models.ManyToManyField(Feature, related_name='constraint+', blank=True)

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=True)
```

And this view and filter:

```
class ResourceFilter(FilterSet):
    constraints = django_filters.CharFilter(name='constraints__name')

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ['constraints']


class ResourceViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ResourceSerializer
    filter_class = ResourceFilter
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

/api/resource/?constraints=testconstraint works fine, but I want /api/resource/ to only return the Resources that have no constraints.

I can reduce the queryset, but it feels like something django_filters could solve. Is it?:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if 'constraints' not in self.request.query_params:
        return Resource.objects.filter(constraints=None)
    else:
        return Resource.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the `qs` property on the FilterSet subclass, where you can manipulate the filtered query and access the request object:

Try with this:

```
class ResourceFilter(FilterSet):

    constraints = django_filters.CharFilter(name='constraints__name')

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ['constraints']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent_qs = super(ResourceFilter, self).qs
        if 'constraints' in self.request.query_params:
            return parent_qs
        else:
            return parent_qs.filter(constraints=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `CharFilter` overriding `filter`:

```
class OrNoneCharFilter(CharFilter):   
    def filter(self, qs, value):
       if value is None: 
           return qs.filter(constraints=None)

       return super().filter(qs, value)
```